# Where can I edit existing queries defined in Access 2007?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm having to do some maintenance on a Access 2007 application. I've never really used it before so I'm struggling to figure out where things are hidden. This application is broken up into two ACCDB's - one for the application, one with the data. Inside of the application I am attempting to track down where various queries are defined but not having much luck.

I've looked in the data ACCDB and selected the "Queries" category off the sidebar. The queries are not there. Inside of the Visual Basic editor of the application ACCDB, they also don't appear in the "Microsoft Office Access Class Objects".

If I click on "Create", then Query Design it seems to open a designer where I can select these queries. However, I still can't seem to figure out how to actually edit existing ones (which is what I really want to do).

Where on earth can I edit them?

Comment: When you open them in the Queries sidebar, what do you see?  There should be a design icon at the top of the resulting window, which drops down to display a `SQL` icon.  I'm thinking of old versions of Access, as that's how it was done.  They did a good job of hiding SQL then too.

Comment: Well, from within the application ACCDB I can't figure out how to open the Queries sidebar. It appears automatically when I open the ACCDB that contains the data (but unfortunately that isn't the file the queries are defined in).

Answer (score 0):

On the sidebar on the left you can select different categories like `Tables`, `Queries` etc.; however, queries can also be stored in the `RecordSource` of `Forms`, `Reports` and the `RowSource` of controls. For instance `ListBox` and `ComboBox` have a `RowSource` property. Queries can be stored as SQL strings in VBA code or Macros or they can even be created dynamically with VBA.